# material_tabs set by default to first tab, How to change it to the third tab

Tags: r, material-ui, shinydashboard

I have made a shiny app and I cant figure out how to change the default tab to tab 3. As soon as i open the app, it shows by default page in tab1.

The reason for that is I am working in Arabic dashbord ( Right to left ). So people will look to the first tab in the right ( 3 tab). So I put the third tab as home page But the app always open by default to the firs tab.

If there is a way to use something like Select=3

[image: App]

Comment: the code is:                                                    material_tabs(
    tabs  = c( 
    "التحليل المتقدم" = "GRP",
    "التحليل الوصفي" = "disAnal",
    "الصفحة الرئيسية" = "home"  
    ),color =1 #"deep-purple")

Comment: Try adding an attribute: value=3

Comment: It can not be used with material_tabs